# Get back status of silent installation of SQL Server service pack

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am working on an automation tool where I have to do end to end automation of  service pack upgrade.

Silent installation command executing from command prompt

```
param([string]$servername,[string]$path)
#param([string]$instance)

#$path1="d:\sysdba\"
#$path2= $path1 "+" $path


Try
{

$SqlQuery = "SELECT  @@SERVICENAME"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection



$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $Servername; Database = master; Integrated Security = SSPI;"
write-host $SqlConnection.ConnectionString 

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$instancename = $DataSet.Tables[0].rows[0].Column1
Write-Host $instancename 
#$DataSet.Tables[0] | out-file "C:\temp\version.csv"



#$command=$path1

write-host $servername
write-host $instancename

$arg1="/instancename=$instancename"
$arg2= "/quiet" 
$arg3= "/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=TRUE"

write-host $arg1
write-host $instancename
# D:\sysdba\SQLServer2008R2SP2-KB2630458-x64-ENU.exe  /instancename=SQLINST /quiet  /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=”TRUE” | Out-File d:\sysdba\test.txt


& $path $arg1 $arg2 $arg3

          Write-Host "Success." 
Write-Host "true"  | out-file "D:\temp\installation.csv"

}

Catch

{
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White "Fail" 


        $errText =  $Error[0].ToString() 


            if ($errText.Contains("network-related")) 


        {Write-Host "Connection Error. Check server name, port, firewall."}   

        Write-Host $errText 


        continue 


}
```

Code is working perfectly fine, my question is how to know that installation is failed passed reboot required, option I am seeing is `summary.txt` file from Microsoft but then I need to keep on checking.

Is there a way I can check completion of installation process?

Comment: `Start-Process -Wait "...-ENU.exe" -ArgumentList  "/instancename=... /quiet ..."`.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you mean "how do I verify the upgrade worked after that", that's fairly simple: check `SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')`. If it succeeded, this version should match the product version of the installation file (except with a build number of 0). If it doesn't, a human being should read the logs to find out what happened.

Comment: Start-Process -Wait "...-ENU.exe" -ArgumentList "/instancename=... /quiet ..." this will work?? serverproperty is way to check sp version but how do i knw whn to execute that ??i shd get some status of installation

Comment: so instead of writing & $path $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 i shd write start-process -wait

Comment: `Start-Process -Wait` *will* wait for the installation to complete. It will not give back a meaningful error code if it failed, however.

Comment: ok let me try will share results

Comment: Start-Process -Wait $path $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 this isnt working any problem iam doing

Comment: , it says positional parameter cannot be found that accept argument quiet